# Vue blank page after separating list item component

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have the following code:

ReceiptList.vue

```
<template>
Hello
<div class="list-container">  
        <ul>
            <ReceiptListItem/>
        </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ReceiptListItem } from '@/components/ReceiptListItem.vue' 

</script>
```

ReceiptListItem.vue

```
<template> 
<li>
    <div class="two-rows">
        <div class="line-spread">
            <span class="id">1212121</span>
        </div>
        <div class="line-spread">
            <span class="">1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</template>
    
<script setup>
</script>
```

As soon as I comment out `ReceiptListItem` from template and script in `ReceiptList.vue` it works fine and shows Hello. Howewer with present`ReceiptListItem` the page becomes blank.
What could be the reason of this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a named import, so you have to import the component without the curly braces:

```
import ReceiptListItem from '@/components/ReceiptListItem.vue'
```

instead of

```
import {ReceiptListItem} from '@/components/ReceiptListItem.vue'
```

Rest seems to work when I put it into a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqlUk1vwjAM/StRLlyg1cYNdUjbhDSmaZvYjrlUrWFhaRLFKSAh/vuclI+WIS60hzZ+z/az87b80dpkVQMf8cxDZVXuYSz0CyhlhM5KuWKFyhEfBFcS/aAw2udSgxN8zJjQbP9ktaK0wylGZlCAtP6N0qZUOm3hWRrpWUr147fVmo5YOEpkCL62MSIra5xnZxXZ3JmK9ZL0LB7m6ZG2ULgpRUV4n3sk9XO5SJZoNA28DYIEL0xlpQL3Yb00GgUfsYgELKc1rF9jzLsa+od48QPF74X4EjchJvinAwS3AsGPmM/dAnwDT77eYUP/R7AyZa2IfQWcARpVB40N7anWJclu8aLaadyV1ItvnGw8aDwMFYQG5i7yBactPV8Z/SR3mAxjntA72uKFZXfMQ4vPlNxfdsdAfm0GzqypTdsKXYtpGKB1kJcdUiSizfWRKQPh7j6+dMsEdezV+OrGHqHD1don/8aBOzaOS/xn5bYhd3+N7xt0)